# Vuejs format credit card number not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a payment gateway component, when you choose credit card I use the **_formatCreditCard** method to leave the credit card number in this format:
4444 2442 4342 3434

This is my function:

```
_formatCreditCard: function() {

        var numberChunks = this.credit_card_number.match(/.{1,4}/g);

        if (numberChunks) {
          this.credit_card_number = numberChunks.join(' ');

        }
        else
          return '';

      }
```

And this is my component:

```
Vue.component('payment-methods', {

   template : '<div>\
                <template>\
                    <div class="radio col-xs-12">\
                      <label><input type="radio" v-model="pick" name="payment_method" value="CARD"> <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt"></i> Tarjeta</label>\
                    </div>\
                    <div id="creditCard" class="col-xs-12" v-if="pick == credit_card">\
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">\
                        <label for="cardholderName">Titular de la tarjeta</label>\
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardholderName" name="credit_card[holder_name]">\
                      </div>\
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-9">\
                        <label for="cardNumber">Número de tarjeta</label>\
                        <input v-model="credit_card_number" type="text" class="form-control" id="cardNumber" name="credit_card[number]" @keyup="_formatCreditCard">\
                      </div>\
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-3">\
                        <label for="credit_card_number">CVN <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></label>\
                        <input id="cvn" type="text" class="form-control" name="credit_card[cvn]">\
                      </div>\
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">\
                        <label for="holder_name">Fecha de vencimiento <span class="subtitle">(ej: 06/26)</span></label><br>\
                        <div class="date-element">\
                          <select id="expiryDateMM" \
                                  name="credit_card[expiry_date_mm]"\
                                  class="form-control">\
                            <option v-for="month in months">{{month}}</option>\
                          </select>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="divider">/</div>\
                        <div class="date-element">\
                          <select id="expiryDateYY"\
                                name="credit_card[expiry_date_yy]"\
                                class="form-control">\
                          <option v-for="year in years">{{year}}</option>\
                        </select>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="radio col-xs-12">\
                      <label><input type="radio" v-model="pick" name="payment_method" value="PAYPAL"> <i class="fa fa-cc-paypal"></i> Paypal</label>\
                    </div>\
                    <div id="paypal" class="col-xs-12" v-if="pick == paypal">\
                      <p class="payment-info">\
                      Tanto si eres cliente de Paypal como si no, puedes realizar pagos a través de esta plataforma. Es el método más popular de pagos online en todo el mundo.\
                      </p>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="radio col-xs-12">\
                      <label><input type="radio" v-model="pick" name="payment_method" value="BANK_TRANSFER"> <i class="fa fa-bank"></i> Transferencia</label>\
                    </div>\
                    <div id="bankTransfer" class="col-xs-12" v-if="pick == bank_transfer">\
                      <p class="payment-info">\
                      El pedido será enviado una vez recibamos el ingreso o  transferencia. Recuerda que las transferencias pueden tardar 2-3 días hábiles en recibirse y los ingresos al menos 24 h.\
                      </p>\
                    </div>\
                </template>\
               </div>',    


    data: function()
    {
       return {
            pick:   'CARD',
            credit_card: 'CARD',
            paypal: 'PAYPAL',
            bank_transfer: 'BANK_TRANSFER',
            credit_card_number: '',
       }
    },

    props : ['products','web_general_discount','current_article_size','current_article_model','simple_view_properties'],

    updated: function() {

       if(this.show)
        $('body').addClass('no-scroll')
       else
        $('body').removeClass('no-scroll')

    },

    computed: {

     months: function () {
        return [
          '01', '02', '03', '04',
          '05', '06', '07', '08',
          '09', '10', '11', '12'
        ];
      },

      years: function () {
        var years= [];
        var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear() % 2000;

        for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++)
          years.push(currentYear + i);

        return years;
      },




    },


    mounted: function() {


    },

    methods: {    

      _formatCreditCard: function() {

        var numberChunks = this.credit_card_number.match(/.{1,4}/g);

        if (numberChunks) {
          this.credit_card_number = numberChunks.join(' ');

        }
        else
          return '';

      }


    }

});
```

it currently doesn't work and I get this as a result:
[image]

I want this result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

look like you forgot to account for the spaces of the string? if i understand it right.
If you remove the spaces of the string before anything, won't that fix the problem?
I made a sample with jquery and html like this at jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/uwry7xn7/

```
$( "#input" ).keyup(function(e) {
  //.replace(/\s/g, ''); is for removing spaces
  var str = $(e.currentTarget).val().replace(/\s/g, '');
  var numberChunks = str.match(/.{1,4}/g);
  console.log(numberChunks)
  var result = numberChunks.join(' ');
  console.log(result)
  $(e.currentTarget).val(result)
});
```

and the jquery does the job.

Comment: So more of a js logic problem, then vue problem :)

Comment: i need this for vuejs logic

Comment: You can do that. just take the credit_card_number out in a variable, do the code, save it back in credit_card_number. since you bind you html on this.

Comment: you get replace is not a function on your credit_Card_number.replace() ?

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle, where it fails, i can see what is wrong, and see if i can fix it for you. is hard to help with getting my hands in it. my snippet should do the job. using something similar in my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple function

*in your script:*

```
formatCardNumber(event) {
        let value = event.target.value;
        if(!value) return

        this.cardNumber = value.replaceAll(" ", "")
        .split("")
        .map((v, index) => {
            if(index > 0 && index % 4 == 0 ) {
                return " " + v
            }else {
                return v
            }
        }).join("")
    }
```

*in your html template*

```
<input v-model="cardNumber" @keyup="formatCardNumber($event)" type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9\s]{13,19}" maxlength="19" placeholder="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx">
```

*P.S: the cardNumber is in your data function that returns the initial reactive state for the component instance (https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data)*

**Tip:**
for the format of the expiry date (xx/xx) you can use the same function but inside the 'map' change the return " " by "/" and modulo 4 by 2

Have a good day